# Can't set custom options in .rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, config, formatter

I'm trying to put some custom options in my `.rspec` because I'd like to have [this custom formatter](https://github.com/thekompanee/fuubar).

This is the only content of my `.rspec` file:

```
--format Fuubar
--color
```

When i'm launching my tests with

> rspec some_spec.rb

nothing is happening, but when I'm using

> rspec some_spec.rb --format Fuubar --color spec

or putting the options in my `spec_helper.rb`

```
config.color = true
config.formatter = "Fuubar"
```

everything is working fine, so i think there's something I'm missing with the `.rspec` file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the location of the `.rspec` file.
The correct structure should be

-- my_tests/
---- spec/
------ folder1/
------ folder2/
------ folder3/
------ spec_helper.rb
----- .rspec

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `.rspec` file located? There is only 3 places where Rspec will look for this file:

- `$PROJECT_ROOT/.rspec-local`
- `$PROJECT_ROOT/.rspec`
- `~/.rspec`

> `$PROJECT_ROOT` is not an actual environment variable, but the full path to your project.

Please make sure your `.rspec` file is in one of these locations, and not inside the `spec` directory or something like that.

Source: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/configuration/read-command-line-configuration-options-from-files

Comment: Then you might be dealing with a permissions problem, can you post a listing for `ls -lh`? Also you may want to try using `strace` with the `-e open` flag to see what files rspec is trying to read.

Comment: with `ls -lh`my .rspec file is not appearing... permissions are -rw-r--r--

Comment: Sorry, `ls -lha`, forgot that you need the `a` option to show dot files. Can you also try using `~/.rspec` (home dir) and see if that works?

Comment: -rw-r--r--   1 my_user  my_group    23B 16 dic 16:39 .rspec

Comment: These permissions sound ok. I would try a few other things, like using one of the other file names / locations and closing and opening a new terminal. If you can't fix it I can take a look later via team viewer or something like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98139/discussion-between-jesus-castello-and-fabersky).